# fetch only 6 digit verification code from yopmail

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

while registering an account with yopmail email address , a verification code is sent on my yopmail account ,which is like below on doing inspect
Your code is: 123456
want to store this value and use this in another method where enter verification code field is written
and i want to insert this only "123456"(not "Your code is:") in another field in order to navigate to next page.

can you please help me on how to automate this in selenium eclipse. i am new in selenium.

```java
driver.get("https://yopmail.com/");

driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("steve_123");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='material-icons-outlined f36']")).click();  

driver.manage().window().maximize();

Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.id("refresh")).click();

boolean response = (driver.getCurrentUrl().indent(6).contains("Your code is:"));
```

small request - any automation tester MSteam group?